# GPS coordination interpolation/smoothing

Tags: c++, gps, interpolation, smoothing

I'm looking for a suitable algorithm to interpolate and smooth 1Hz GPS logged (on file) coordinations up to 60Hz.

While I've found a couple of interpolation algorithms, I couldn't locate a suitable smoothing algorithm which handles interpolation as well.

ALGLIB sounds good for interpolation- but what for smoothing?

Comment: Don't you maybe want extrapolation? The 1Hz values you get are already "old" and by smoothing them for the next second you delay them even more...

Comment: No, I mean interpolation. The values are from a logged file, not realtime. Question edited for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Since GPS cooridinates are already heavily Kalmann filtered, i would only apply a linear interplation between to coordiantes.
Smoothing makes the positions wrong. When the device moves, coordinates are already smooth. There is usually no need to smooth further.
If you have problems when the device is standing still, then remove that positions.

Consider using a running average filter to smooth data, Set filter window to 0,5 -1s; current position is at center of window. Delay will be half window size.

Depending on the implementation you will use the first half window, and the last. (Which would not be a problem)

Comment: Only linear interpolation would mean, that each location point is touched - something I want to avoid, otherwise the visualisation in realtime (hence 60Hz) of the logged points would wobble between the the known points.

Comment: And no, unfortunate, the coordinates are not smooth in movement.

Comment: How fast moving, when they are not smooth? pedestrian or automotive?

Comment: Ok 60Hz, this is then unfiltered data from the GPS receiver. Makes this sense for your task? GPS receiver uses a Kalmann filter to smooth, but they have more information than you, so usually they can better smooth. (uBlox and Sirf)

Comment: It's an aeroplane, 0-300kt and the known points visualized are smooth once zoomed out in 2d view, not so smooth upon closer investigation.

Comment: True about the kalman filtering, but I do need to visualize the flight path in realtime on a visual system requiring 60Hz and I want to avoid wobbling or stuttering, hence the quest for a smoothing/interpolating algorithm.

Comment: What about setting to 1hZ, The it should be smooth

Comment: To be precise, not the exact location is important but a smooth movement in realtime. The location can be visualized on known (and thus exact GPS coords) on any type of map, but the flight path visualization must be smooth.

Comment: The visual system runs at 60Hz in 3D and needs 60 position updates per second. Driving it at 1Hz isn't possible or it will hop from one second to the next...

Comment: Or using a running average filter with filter windows 0,5s - 1s,this should work, you can optimize by using a triangle window

Comment: I'm looking to an algo similar to Figure 3 on http://www.geocomputation.org/2007/1B-Algorithms_and_Architecture1/1B2.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, but I can't see it (yet) how I can get a smooth line between two points, allowing to get 60 points out of it... It's been a long week :)

Comment: I have read the paper, maybe works, but to complex, cost to much, the running average is ready tommorow. The algo in the article may cost you 4 weeks. And then its unclesar how it behaves with 10.000 points. The tetsdata set had only 100 points. Hopefully it has some window too ( I asume)

Comment: You are talking of two distinct problems: 1) smoothing distorted GPS data from a bad reciever or slow movement; 2) animating a path for visual presenation. at point 2) you simply lineraly interpolate between two positions. point 1) is a prepocessing step

Comment: Linear interpolation between xa, and xb, result in xi: for (int i = 0; i <=60; i++) { xi = xa*(1.0 - (i/60.0) + xb * (i/60.0);  same for y; plot(xi,yi)}

Comment: Isn't a linear interpolation between two points a straight line? That won't fit for "smooth" visualization.

Comment: Yes it is, but in preprocessing step, with average filter you smoothed out. conisder using 10hz in preprocessing step, then 60hz for animation. What is your GPS input data? 1Hz?

Comment: I think the average filter isn't working too good on narrow turns.

Comment: Yes maybe, but a plane with narrow turns?

Comment: is this a 3D visualisation or 2D, you know that height data is horrible from GPS

Comment: 3D - height will be treated likewise but it's a different source.